# String Hex to Byte Array

Tags: c++, parsing, arduino, hex, microcontroller

How do I convert a String which has hex values to a byte array that has those hex values? I am using Arduino by the way.

This:

```
String s = "0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff";
```

Needs to be converted to this:

```
char test[] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
```

I used the following procedure. It does convert it, however, each hex value is saved as a character as opposed to hex value:

```
unsigned int str_len = s.length()+1;
char charArray[str_len];
s.toCharArray(charArray, str_len);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Arduino (libraries) for any purpose, least of all for the purpose of learning. As for how to do the conversion, `man strtoul`.

Comment: `char test[] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};` -> "*warning: overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from '255' to '-1' [-Woverflow]*".

Comment: @HamidReza makes sense but how do i write an algorithm for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need an array of hex values i.e. array of integers from the String `s`.
Thogh from `char test[] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};` , it seems you want a char array.
If you add the code below after your code you will get an integer array named `hexn` which will contain your hex values.

```
    int i,hexn[20],k=0,j;
    char tmp[8];
    for (i=0;charArray[i]!='\0' ;i++){
        if(charArray[i]=='x' && charArray[i-1]=='0'){
            j=0;
            while(charArray[i]!=','){
                tmp[j++]=charArray[++i];
                if (charArray[i]=='\0')
                    break;
            }
            sscanf(tmp,"%x",&hexn[k++]);
        }
    }
```

Now if you really need `char test[] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};`, I suppose you are not getting the opening and closing braces, i.e. `{` and `}`.
in that case you can use the concatenation operator.
You can to do something like this before your code,

`String s2 = String('{') + s + String('}');`

Hope it will help you.